# Why gdb is not working in Linux with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, gdb

I am working on Visual Studio Code But I am unable to debug my c++ code . I searched a lot but I only found one link which is following and it does not helped me .
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126945/how-can-i-solve-unable-to-open-raise-c-errorvscode-linux)

Following is my launch.json file :

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/mypro",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

> **Error :** vsc Unable to open 'raise.c': Unable to read file (Error: File not found (/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c))

***Above error I am getting when I launched debugger in visual studio code .Please anyone who have an idea about that please help me . Thanks in advance !!***

Comment: just ignore the error, its saying it can't find the source code for the c runtime library which is presumably where your code is triggering a breakpoint, if you look at the call stack and move up into your code it'll probably work normally

Comment: First instinct is that all the proper packages are not installed. Distro and version?

Comment: @AlanBirtles : That's the problem I am unable to move forward , It terminates from gdb .

Comment: @sweenish : Version: 1.36.1
Commit: 2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529
Date: 2019-07-08T22:55:08.091Z
Electron: 4.2.5
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.0.0-36-generic

Comment: @AlanBirtles : following error I am getting when I am doing step over :terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 18446744073709551615) >= this->size() (which is 12)
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-tasvd7js.uib" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-q2fwlvfq.lb5"

Comment: Your code throws an exception. Take a look at the call stack to find which function throws. You have no problem with GDB. Probably, you're trying to call `operator[]` with negative index.

Comment: @Evg : then why it works fine without gdb ? My code is working fine but during debugging it is not working . even command line gdb it works fine . It giving me error in only VSC .

Comment: @SatinderSingh, it might involve undefined behaviour, for example. The problem is in your code, not in GDB.

Comment: @Evg : Sorry to say , But you are wrong here, According to me VSC does not have proper support of gdb in linux . Thant is the bug in VSC .

Comment: @SatinderSingh, I use VSCode with GDB on every day basis and I see the message about missing `raise.c` once in a while. `std::out_of_range' what(): vector::_M_range_check` is the real bug, and it has nothing to do with VSCode or GDB.

Comment: @SatinderSingh You didn't answer my question. VS Code and gdb play together great in Linux. You are having issues, not VS Code.